# Determine if PowerShell script has been dot-sourced

Tags: powershell

From a PowerShell script, how can I determine if the script has been dot-sourced, i.e. it has been called with

```
. .\myscript.ps1
```

rather than

```
.\myscript.ps1
```

*NOTE* an interesting blog post (also) about this: http://poshoholic.com/2008/03/18/powershell-deep-dive-using-myinvocation-and-invoke-expression-to-support-dot-sourcing-and-direct-invocation-in-shared-powershell-scripts/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check $myinvocation.line
It will show the line that was used to call the script.

```
 PS C:\scripts\test> gc test.ps1
 $myinvocation.line

 PS C:\scripts\test> ./test.ps1
 ./test.ps1

 PS C:\scripts\test> . ./test.ps1
 . ./test.ps1
```

You can also check the .invocationname property.  If the script was dot-sourced, it will just be a dot. If not, is will be ./scriptname.ps1

Comment: Thanks, InvocationName was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The .Invocationname seems best, with "line" the first character might be a dot with relative path ..\test.ps1 when NOT dot surce, 
or when dot sourced the next character might not be a space. (parens, quotes, $( etc)
Then add @mklement0 exception below.

Comment: I think a better solution to check if script has been dot-sourced would be to check if `$MyInvocation.CommandOrigin -ieq 'Internal'`. But you do you.

Comment: @Diti,  `$MyInvocation.CommandOrigin -eq 'Internal'` can yield _false positives_, such as with `& { ./script.ps1 }`

Answer (score 20):

To complement [mjolinor's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4876169/45375):

**tl;dr**

```
$isDotSourced = $MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq '.' -or $MyInvocation.Line -eq ''
```

---

While `$MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq '.'` *mostly* tells you whether a given script is being dot-sourced, there is one **exception**:

When you run a script from the - obsolescent<sup>[1]</sup> - **Windows PowerShell ISE** with `Debug > Run/Continue` (<kbd>F5</kbd>), it is *implicitly* sourced, yet `$MyInvocation.InvocationName` contains the full script filename rather than `.` However, you can detect this case by checking if `$MyInvocation.Line` is *empty*.

(The PIC (PowerShell Integrated Console) that comes with [**Visual Studio Code**](https://code.visualstudio.com/)'s [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) *used to* behave this way, but as of at least version v2023.1.0 submits explicit dot-sourcing commands).

Note: Detecting whether a *function* is being dot-sourced is *not* subject to the exception above, so testing for `$MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq '.'` is sufficient (but the above will work too).

---

<sup>[1] The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md). The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).</sup>

Comment: Excellent, I spent way to much time determing this from LINE (due to all sorts of weird exceptions) and you guys have it simple and even this exception that I didn't know aobut.
Thx