# How can I tell if my powershell script was run or dot-included?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a script, and it primarily defines just one function. If the script is merely included

```
. .\MyScript.ps1
```

Then I want to let it be used as a regular function

```
My-Script <args>
```

But if it's right-click-run from Explorer I want to have it trigger a portion of the file to be run making the file self-calling. (eg: at the end of the file include some `My-Script <args>` of my own devise that are already in the file)

Can this be done?

If there is a requirement for PowerShell 2.0 or 3.0, that can be arranged as a pre-req if need be.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875912/determine-if-powershell-script-has-been-dot-sourced

Comment: pretty close. I'll test later and let you know.