# Determine if Powershell script started in main scope?

Tags: python, powershell

I am a beginner Powershell user.  I am writing some script files (.ps1)

I would like to determine how my script was invoked:

Was is the "main" script or was it dot sourced from another file?

In python, I would use something like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Is there something similar in PowerShell?

**Update**

After reading the answers, I am using the following at the end of my .ps1 file:

```
if ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -ne '.')
{
  # do "main" stuff here
}
```

Any answers that include how this could fail are welcome.

It appears this is a duplicate question, I just didn't use the right search terms:
[Determine if PowerShell script has been dot-sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875912/determine-if-powershell-script-has-been-dot-sourced?rq=1)

Comment: [about_Scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx)

Comment: @HyperAnthony thanks for the link.  Is there a equivalent one-liner for PowerShell to the python version?  I understand that PowerShell scripts are ran from top to bottom.  So I'd like to put a test condition near the bottom of my script that only if it passes, does the remainder of the script run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're wanting to know how it was invoked, have a look at the $myinvocation automatic variable.

If you just want to test if you're in the global scope:

```
Try {if (get-variable args -scope 1){$true}}
Catch {$false}
```

should return $true if you're running in a child scope.  If you're already in the global scope, there is no parent scope and it will throw an error and return $false.

Comment: thank you, this seems to be good information.  Do you know if the $myinvocation.CommandOrigin would give me what I want?  My preliminary testing seems to show 'Runspace' if I started the script from powershell, and 'Internal' if another script is calling it?  I have not found any detailed info on the CommandOrigin member.

Comment: I also see the InvocationName which seems to be either a '.' or the name of the script?  Maybe this is a better way?

Comment: I don't know Python, so I'm not quite sure what to tell you to look for that would be the analog of that Python command.

Comment: Thanks!  Every scope gets initialized with it's own $args, so it should always be there :).