# See the docstring of my function with Visual Studio Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Visual Studio Code, I'm starting to use it to develop PowerShell scripts.

[image: Function declaration]

I see that when I let my cursor on the name of a function I get an overview of the parameters of the function, yet when I do it with my own custom functions, it does not do it.

How do I declare a documentation for my PowerShell functions that can be displayed in the overview by Visual Studio Code ?

I tried to do this :

```
<#
.Description
Get-Function displays the name and syntax of all functions in the session.
#>
function test([string]$print){}


<# Setup the working directories if they do not exist #>
If(!(Test-Path $WORKING_DIRECTORY)) {test}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `.PARAMETER` to the description worked for me. Also note I believe you have to save and run the script once for it to show.

```
<#
.Description
Get-Function displays the name and syntax of all functions in the session.
.PARAMETER  
#>

function test([string]$print){Write-Host $print}

If(Test-Path $env:userprofile) {test -print "Test123"}
```

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was incorrect, though reading up on [Comment Based Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-6) is still a good idea for generally documenting your cmdlets.

In order for `vscode` to be able to know about your function definitions, the function needs to be defined in its internal Powershell host. If you can open the `Powershell Integrated` terminal, you can dot-source (run the script like `. myScript.ps1` to read the function definitions in. You may need to [make sure the script wasn't dot-sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875912/determine-if-powershell-script-has-been-dot-sourced) before running any code to execute (basically put your runtime code in an if block checking if the script was dot-sourced but leave your function definitions outside of this conditional).

Once the script has been dot-sourced in the `Powershell Integrated` terminal you will get the usage tooltip popup like you want. To make this "automatic", dot-source the script from `$profile` as resolved from the `vsvode` terminal.

This isn't particularly ideal and I am hoping to find a more streamlined solution, as having to dot-source every script I'm working with is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save and run the script, so changes in the inline documentation is recognized. I also can recommend using the `.SYNOPSIS` 'tag', that way it is even possible to read the text.

Example:

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Returns something
#>
function Get-SomeThing {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Path
    )

}
```

shows something like this when hovering the function name or for code completion:

[image: when hovering the function name]

[image: code completion]