# Powershell: Why can't I add aliases in functions?

Tags: powershell, function, alias, profile

I tried adding several aliases in my powershell profile script. For organization reasons I wanted to keep those in a function which I would call at the end of said profile. I discovered that, while the function can be called from inside or outside the script without any problems, the aliases don't apply to my current powershell session. Only when I add them one at a time in the profile script, they would be usable.

This is my script as it is right now

```
function Populate-Aliases() {
  New-Alias grep Select-String
  New-Alias touch New-Item
  New-Alias lsa dir -Force
}

Populate-Aliases
```

I'm also certain the script is executed when I create a new ps session, as is proven by inserting any output in the function. It's just the aliases that don't apply to my session.

I tried creating the aliases via function in the profile script, which didn't work. I also tried declaring a function from within the terminal as such:

```
function al(){New-Alias lsa dir -Force}
al
lsa
```

This did also not work which leads me to believe that I'm making some kind of mistake or creating aliases in functions is not supported (which I could not quite understand why that would be the case).

Creating an alias via New-Alias in the cli works without any problem. Also just adding the New-Alias statement to the profile script works, when it is not enclosed in a function.

Comment: I quess you will need to set the [`-Scooe Global`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-alias#-scope) otherwise it will only work within the function.

Answer (score 3):

> [`-Scope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias#-scope)
> Specifies the scope in which this alias is valid. The default value is Local. For more information, [see about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes).

This means that, by default, the concerned alias is only available in the scope of the function:

```
function Test {
    New-Alias Show Write-Host
    Show 'This works'
}
Test
Show 'but this does not work'
```

Unless you will set the `-scope` to `global`:

```
function Test {
    New-Alias -Scope Global Show Write-Host
    Show 'This works'
}
Test
Show 'And this works too'
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [iRon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75268939/45375):

While a function name such as `Populate-Aliases` - or perhaps better, using an [approved verb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands), `Add-CustomAliases` - does suggest modification of the caller's state, it is **generally better to let the *caller* make the choice to have its state modified**, by using **`.` , the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-)**, which executes the specified function or script *directly in the caller's scope* rather than in a *child* scope (as is the default and as happens when you use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-)).

Thus, you could leave your function as-is and simply invoke it in your `$PROFILE` file as follows:

```bash
# Dot-source the function call, so that it runs directly in the current scope
# (which inside $PROFILE is the *global* scope), causing the aliases to
# become globally defined.
. Populate-Aliases
```

Note that this technique also allows you to out-source the alias definitions to a *script file*; say you place them in an `CustomAliases.ps1` file alongside your `$PROFILE` file, you can then define them globally as follows:

```bash
# Ditto, via an external .ps1 file.
. $PSScriptRoot/CustomAliases.ps1
```

The only challenge is that *not* using `.`  for invocation then becomes effectively a quiet no-op. The function's / script's comment-based help could make that clear, but you can also implement a **runtime check to enforce dot-sourced invocation**:

```bash
function Add-CustomAliases {

  # Ensure that the function was invoked with dot-sourcing.
  if ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -ne '.') { 
    throw "Please invoke this function dot-sourced."
  }

  New-Alias grep Select-String
  New-Alias touch New-Item
  New-Alias lsa dir -Force
}

. Add-CustomAliases # OK

Add-CustomAliases # Throws an error, due to using dot-sourcing.
```

Note: With the *script-file* implementation, an extended check is necessary for robustness (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33855217/45375)).

```bash
# Content of CustomAliases.ps1

# Ensure that the script was invoked with dot-sourcing.
if (-not ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq '.' -or $MyInvocation.Line -eq '')) {
  throw "Please invoke this script dot-sourced."
}

New-Alias grep Select-String
New-Alias touch New-Item
New-Alias lsa dir -Force
```